# UISearchDisplayController table view with two search bars, table view not scrolling properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm converting my app so that it works with iOS 7. On one part of the app I have two search bars, each with a UISearchDisplayController associated with it. As I search UISearchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView, the bottom of the table view is not stopping  at the correct spot. [image]

The same thing happens with the bottom UISearchDisplayController.

If anyone has had any similar issues when converting to iOS 7 please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the table view's content inset was set to the height of the keyboard. So when the keyboard was dismissed, the table view thought it was still up. So I changed the content inset of the table view to 0 in -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView, and it works.

Comment: it helped me. but I set content inset to 0 for search display controller